# Create a log note in a record through controller

Tags: odoo

I created a record of crm.lead model through controller, and I also want to upload image or file in log note.

```py
class RequestForQuote(http.Controller):

    @route('/form/sinsert', type="http", auth="public", website=True, csrf=True)
    def qoute_application_process(self,**kwargs):
        values = {}

        for field_name, field_value in kwargs.items():
            values[field_name] = field_value
        internal_notes = values['comment'] + ' , ' +values['commercial_company_name'] + ", " +values['contact_address']+ ' ' +values['contact_city'] +' '+ \
                        values['contact_state'] +' '+values['zip'] + ', '+ values['meeting_ids']
        name = values['first_name'] +' '+values['last_name']

        opportunity = request.env['crm.lead'].sudo().create({'name': name ,'date_deadline':values['date'],'email_from':values['email'],
                                            'description':internal_notes,'type':'opportunity'
                                })
        return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/form/thankyou')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yee1b.png)

Comment: And what is the question now?

Comment: I can create a record in crm.lead model using controller , now I want to attach file or image in message_ids (Log Note) against this created record using controller.

Comment: it is better to edit your question than to add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To create an internal note, you just need to call `self.message_post`:

```
self.message_post(body="Internal note", attachments=[('Image', self.partner_id.image)])
```

You can read more at [mail.thread](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/mail/mail_thread.py#L1590)